# Write range value to txt file

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub export_ra_file_txt_2()
Dim i As Integer
Dim FSO As Object
For i = 2 To 12
Workbooks("file_name").Sheets("Raw").Cells(i, 1).Copy
Workbooks("file_name").Sheets("name").Range("B2").PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteValues
Workbooks("file_name").Sheets("name").Range("D1:D55").Copy

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FileToCreate = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Desktop\File ini\" & Workbooks("file_name").Sheets("Raw").Cells(i, 1).Value & ".ini")

FileToCreate.Write "Workbooks("file_name").Sheets("name").Range("D1:D55")"

FileToCreate.Close
Next
End Sub
```

I try to copy the value of Workbooks("file_name").Sheets("name").Range("D1:D55") and write to txt file. This is my VBA code. Someone can help me, Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you can't just write a range to a text file.  You'll need to go through cell by cell and write each value use something like a `For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name").Range("D1:D55")` loop.  You've also enclosed the workbook range in  your write line in `"` - at best VBA will read that as a text string.  The line where you copy the range D1:D55 doesn't do anything either - you copy the cells, but don't do anything with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each cell in the output range and `Write` that to the file. Try something like:

```
Set FileToCreate = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Desktop\File ini\" & Workbooks("file_name").Sheets("Raw").Cells(i, 1).Value & ".ini")

For Each cellvalue In Workbooks("file_name").Sheets("name").Range("D1:D55")
    FileToCreate.Write cellvalue
Next

FileToCreate.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update Range Multiple Times and Export Each to a Text File

```vb
Sub CreateIniFiles()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("file_name")
    ' If the previous is the workbook containing this code, instead, simply use:
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Lookup
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Sheets("Raw")
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range("A2:A12")
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("name")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("D1:D55")
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\File ini\"
    ' Maybe you want this instead!?
    'FolderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\File ini\"
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The path """ & FolderPath & """ doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim tfile As Object, lcell As Range, lStr As String
    
    For Each lcell In lrg.Cells
        lStr = CStr(lcell.Value)
        sws.Range("B2").Value = lStr ' so 'srg' gets updated?
        Set tfile = fso.CreateTextFile(FolderPath & lStr & ".ini")
        tfile.Write Join(Application.Transpose(srg), vbLf)
        tfile.Close
    Next lcell
    
    MsgBox "Ini-files created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```